# How to make web site Browser Compatible with different screen resolutions?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, cross-browser

I have developed a website having 10 pages and now i am facing a major problem that when i run it on any other machine having more wide screen than my site goes unbalanced and not showing properly as it looks in my own machine.

I want help that how can i make this site browser compatible that can run on any machine with same layout and can run on any screen with same layout.

please provide me help that what should i do ??

Comment: Use CSS framework like Bootstrap, Skeleton etc find here at this site:http://speckyboy.com/2012/08/21/15-more-responsive-css-frameworks-boilerplates-worth-considering/

Comment: You should google on "responsive web design"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a cross-browser compatible website:

- Use only standard compliant coding.
- Don't use browser specific (proprietory) HTML tags and features.

These only work in the browser they were created for and may even break your web page when viewed in another browser.

Validate your web pages.

- Validate your HTML/XHTML coding using the W3C free validation service
- Validate your cascading style sheets using the W3C free validation
  service

For details see a link

http://www.netmechanic.com/products/Browser-Tutorial.shtml

Answer (score 1):

First of all website has nothing to do with what **machine** are you using, it is just **browsers** which render's differently (in your case) because if you know CSS well, you can build a cross browser website.

So in order to make a cross-browser website you need to have strong understanding in html and more importantly CSS, you need to decide whether you want a **fix** layout or a **dynamic/liquid** one, there are loads of books out there, search for responsive designs, learn cross browser CSS, you can also use `screen(width)/print specific stylesheets` to take your website to a better level...also in CSS learn **`POSITIONING`**

Some of the best books to learn web design :

### Adaptive Web Design

 - **Aaron Gustafson**

### Responsive Web Design

 - **Ethan Marcotte**

### Handcrafted CSS: More Bulletproof Web Design

 - **Dan Cederholm and Ethan Marcotte**

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions.

First of all, it has nothing to do with your machine but the browser, you need to make a proper design. There are few fundamental design principles

i.e. liquid layout design - which fits in any screen width and shrinks/grows with screen

Another is fixed layout - This layout remains unchanged irrespective of the screen size.

You should opt for either of one. There are many good CSS templates available freely on the web. What you can do is, use the skeleton of this theme and apply your styles and other elements to create your own.

Browser compatibility is an age old issue which designers deal with different techniques. Some use javascript to detect different browsers and render proper css to suit that browser while some write conditional CSS.

You can choose one of these strategies.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the Responsive Web Design to design your website.

**Three key technical features are the heart of responsive Web design:**

1. Media queries and media query listeners
2. A flexible grid-based layout that uses relative sizing
3. Flexible images and media, through dynamic resizing or CSS

read following link for more information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx